# What mobile front-end framework should I use for developing a mobile-version of an existing desktop site?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm currently maintaining a large e-commerce site developed 7 years ago. It's done entirely in plain PHP (includes everywhere, PHP mixed with HTML and all that stuff).

My task now is to make it usable on mobile devices, and since it would be almost-impossible to make it responsive IMHO, I thought it would be easier to make a separate new project for the mobile version of the site.

So I basically need a front-end mobile framework suitable for this task. I also will need to connect to some functions already developed in the desktop version. What would be the optimal(s) tool(s) in this particular case?

My first idea was simply bootstrap, or bootstrap but combined with a light PHP framework (silex, laravel...), but there are more players out there, like Ionic, jQuery mobile and others.

I need some guidance/light in this sea of options.

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, recommendation questions are not on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm a big fan of bootstrap, mainly because it's so popular so snippets and sample code are out there.  That makes it really fast to develop and save time, and users have seen it so often they just know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobile framework you want to use depends on your knowledge in certain tools like angularJS, node.js and jQuery. For example, if you want to use Ionic, you need a background in node.js. If you want jQuery mobile, you definitely need to know jQuery.

The jQuery mobile is very easy to use if you don't have any node.js background. I would recommend you looking at these two websites:

1. https://jquerymobile.com/
2. http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/